# How can I re-use a variable containing a timestamp throughout a Makefile run

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a simple Makefile to handle my document creation (PDF, HTML, LaTeX, EPUB, DOCX) from a series of Markdown text sources.

Now I want to backup some intermediate files as copies in a separate directory, renaming them in the process by adding a timestamp to their names.

However, I do not get it to work. I define a timestamp variable like this:

```
.PHONY: timestamp
timestamp: ts := `/bin/date "+%Y-%m-%d---%H-%M-%S"`
timestamp:
        @echo Timestamp is $(ts)

%.tex: %.mmd timestamp
        # My commands to create the LaTeX go here. (Simplified for Stackoverflow)
        pandoc  -t latex  -f markdown  -o $(LATEXDIR)/$@  $<
        $(CP) $(LATEXDIR)/$@ $(BACKUPS)/$(ts)---$@
```

(Yes, I'm using tabs in the Makefile -- don't get fooled by the reproduction above, should you copy'n'paste from it...)

When I run `make timestamp` I see the expected output like `Timestamp is 2014-11-01---22-11-10`.

But running `make bookdraft.tex`,...

1. ...my LaTeX file ends up in `$(LATEXDIR)`,
2. ...but the backup copy's name is `---bookdraft.tex` instead of `2014-11-01---22-11-10---bookdraft.tex`

So my `ts`-variable got lost...

I'm a beginner with Makefiles, and several hours of googling and experimenting didn't get me anywhere.

Note, I *could* set the timestamp on the fly within the current target. However, this will change the timestamp for every additional target which is backed up during the same `make` call. But that's not what I want -- I want the timestamp be fixed to the same value for every call of `make`. So somehow I want to set the timestamp variable at the beginning of the Makefile and then re-use it throughout the current run of `make`. (The next run of make should set the value anew.)

I came up with a temporary workaround by writing the timestamp into a file named `.ts` and later reading it again from there:

```
timestamp:
        @echo `/bin/date "+%Y-%m-%d---%H-%M-%S"` > .ts
```

and then later:

```
%.tex: %.mmd timestamp
        # My commands to create the LaTeX go here. (Simplified for Stackoverflow)
        pandoc  -t latex  -f markdown  -o $(LATEXDIR)/$@  $<
        $(CP) $(LATEXDIR)/$@ $(BACKUPS)/`/bin/cat .ts`---$@
```

However, I do not like this duct-tape method very much -- I'm looking for a more elegant, Makefile-ish solution.

---

**Update:**

Jonathan Leffler suggested a solution, but this didn't match my requirement ... or he didn't understand what I want because I didn't explain well enough, or I didn't implement his suggestion correctly. In any case, I can now better illustrate what I do NOT want.

Consider this *Makefile.leffler* (with `<tabs>` done correctly in the code):

```
ts := `/bin/date "+%Y-%m-%d---%H-%M-%S"`

timestamp:
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)
     @sleep 10
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)

dummy:
     @sleep 10
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)
     @sleep 10
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)
```

When I run `make -f Makefile.leffler timestamp dummy`, the output is this:

```
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-58-43
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-58-53
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-59-03
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-59-13
```

And that's **NOT** what I want! I want this:

```
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-58-43
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-58-43
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-58-43
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---01-58-43
```

I hope my goal is now better clarified.

---

### Solution / Update 2:

After a revision of Jonathan's original answer, this now is the solution for the Makefile example:

```
ts := $(shell /bin/date "+%Y-%m-%d---%H-%M-%S")

timestamp:
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)
     @sleep 10
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)

dummy:
     @sleep 10
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)
     @sleep 10
     @echo Timestamp is $(ts)
```

Output of `make -f Makefile.leffler timestamp dummy` is now exactly as I want it:

```
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---02-44-11
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---02-44-11
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---02-44-11
Timestamp is 2014-01-13---02-44-11
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't make `ts` conditional on the target being `timestamp`:

```
ts := $(shell /bin/date "+%Y-%m-%d---%H-%M-%S")

timestamp:
    @echo Timestamp is $(ts)

%.tex: %.mmd
    # My commands to create the LaTeX go here. (Simplified for Stackoverflow)
    pandoc -t latex -f markdown -o $(LATEXDIR)/$@ $<
    $(CP) $(LATEXDIR)/$@ $(BACKUPS)/$(ts)---$@
```

This differs from the previous proposed solution by using the GNU `make` `$(shell ...)` function.  This is evaluated when the macro is defined.  With this change, the output from the test makefile in the revised question is (for example):

```
$ make -f ts.mk
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-16-35
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-16-35
$ make -f ts.mk timestamp dummy
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-16-53
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-16-53
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-16-53
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-16-53
$
```

Or, with timestamps before and after to make it clearer (10 seconds is a horribly long delay, sometimes!), you might get:

```
$ date; make -f ts.mk timestamp dummy; date
Sun Jan 12 17:19:02 PST 2014
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-19-02
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-19-02
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-19-02
Timestamp is 2014-01-12---17-19-02
Sun Jan 12 17:19:32 PST 2014
$
```